# Updating 5 comboboxes with a sql query in java

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox

I have an MS Access database, in which there is a set of tablet names in column name 'tname'. I have 5 comboboxes in java applet. All the 5 comboboxes must update the items in tname, each time when it loads. I used the following code. It adds only the first item in tname to the first combobox only. Other boxes remain empty. But if I update a single combobox, it works. But I need 5 comboboxes to get updated. Kindly guide me through the problem I've made.

```
try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn9=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
Statement st9=conn9.createStatement();
ResultSet rs9=st9.executeQuery("select DISTINCT tname from try");

while(rs9.next())
{
  ct19.addItem(rs9.getString("tname"));
  ct29.addItem(rs9.getString("tname"));
  ct39.addItem(rs9.getString("tname"));
  ct49.addItem(rs9.getString("tname"));
  ct59.addItem(rs9.getString("tname"));
}


conn9.close();
}
```

Comment: you want every value of tname is each cbox or same tname in all cbox ??

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I have 15 tnames for eg. I want those 15 tnames in each of the 5 cboxes.

Comment: is there any event attached to cboxes, if yes then attached to all or not???

Comment: I got it Sir. Actually I added a temp variable, instead of retrieving in each line. And it worked. Thank you.

Comment: please post it as answer

Comment: as i was wondering it should work without using `temp` variable, so i tried it look at my answer and it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried, it works all fine as i was wondering what is the need to have a `temp` variable look at my code, its fully working code

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ResultSetDemo {

    public ResultSetDemo() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox();
        f.add(cb1);
        JComboBox cb2 = new JComboBox();
        f.add(cb2);
        JComboBox cb3 = new JComboBox();
        f.add(cb3);
        JComboBox cb4 = new JComboBox();
        f.add(cb4);
        JComboBox cb5 = new JComboBox();
        f.add(cb5);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name", my_sql_username, mysql_password);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select DISTINCT tname from try");
            while (rs.next()) {
                cb1.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));
                cb2.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));
                cb3.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));
                cb4.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));
                cb5.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));  

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        f.setSize(600, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResultSetDemo();
    }
}
```

it **populates** cboxes with all **rows** in **table**

Comment: @Gomathi so what you got please share.. and accept this answer if it helped you

Comment: I don't know what mistake I made earlier. But, I got it working now, Sir. I have accepted your answer,Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variables named `ct[1-5]9` reference distinct instances of `JComboBox`, "problems may arise if you add duplicate `String` objects." If necessary, you can duplicate the items, as shown in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28E%29).

A better approach is to update a single `DefaultComboBoxModel` that is shared by each `JComboBox` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning each retrieved value for each combobox, assign it to a temp string and assign that to each combobox.

```
String tmp9;
while(rs9.next())
{
  tmp9=rs9.getString("tname");
  ct19.addItem(tmp9);
  ct29.addItem(tmp9);
  ct39.addItem(tmp9);
  ct49.addItem(tmp9);
  ct59.addItem(tmp9);
}
```